# what is the purpose of typedef name *aliasname

Tags: c, typedef

I am studying `struct` and `typedef` and am totally new to coding

```
typedef struct
{
  uint8_t    ID;
  uint8_t    TanID;
  uint8_t    ProductID;
  uint8_t    SetlTme;
  uint8_t    NoOfStep
}product_Config;

typedef product_Config *product_Config_Ptr;
```

I am not getting what is last line is meant for

`typedef product_Config *product_Config_Ptr;`

Comment: Might be less confusing to think of it as `typedef Tank_Config* Tank_Config_Ptr`. Basically just a new type for the pointer.

Comment: I feel that the last typedef is bad taste. You want to know at once when some type is a pointer. But YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `typedef` defines an alias for a type.

In your example `typedef Tank_Config *Tank_Config_Ptr;`  Declares `Tank_Config_Ptr` as an alias for `Tank_Config *`.

So the following definitions are equivalent.

```
Tank_Config *ptr1;
Tank_Config_Ptr ptr2;
```

That being said, it is considered bad practice to hide a pointer inside of a `typedef`.  It masks the fact that a pointer is being used and can cause confusion to readers of the code.

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` in C is used to define new datatypes. These new datatypes are usually just an alias to the existing datatypes, structs, or unions. It is mostly used to define types which make more sense in the context of the code. For example, `size_t` is a standard type in C which may be defined like this (the actual definition may vary on different platforms and implementations as pointed out by chqrlie in the comment)

```
typedef unsigned int size_t;
```

So, when you need a variable which represents size or length of some object, you declare it as a type of `size_t`, this makes the intention of the variable clearer to the reader.

The simplified form of using `typedef` is as follows

```
typedef <some existing datatype or struct> <your_new_type>
```

(But it can be more complicated than that and won't always fit this form. For example if you are trying to typedef a function pointer)

In your example:

```
typedef Tank_Config *Tank_Config_Ptr;
```

You are saying `Tank_Config_Ptr` is a new type which is an alias for the type `Tank_Config *`

Comment: *`size_t` is a common type in C which is defined like this*:  `size_t` is a standard C type that can be defined differently on many platforms.

Comment: @chqrlie Thanks, I have clarified.

Comment: Your syntax definition is a simplification, because the declared typename isn't necessarily at the end of the declaration, any more than it is when declaring a variable.  e.g. `typedef void (*sighandler_t)(int);`.  I don't expect you to explain the whole of `typedef`, but I think you should mention that this is only the simplest form.

Comment: @TobySpeight Yes, I agree. I have added a note. Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typedef; it allows the programmer to write `Tank_Config_Ptr` in place of `Tank_Config *` in the subsequent code, assuming that `Tank_Config` is already defined as a type.

There's little benefit to names like this, unless you have some affliction making it difficult to write or read the `*` character.

In the first example, it allows `product_Config` to be written in place of `struct { uint8_t ID; uint8_t TanID; uint8_t ProductID; uint8_t SetlTme;  uint8_t NoOfStep}`.  That is a Good Thing.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the most significant advantage of using typedef to define pointer types is that it allows a common type to be specified for multiple variables in a declaration.  If one wants two pointers to a Tank_Config and doesn't have a typedef for the pointer, one would either have to write:

```
Tank_Config *first, *last;
```

or else

```
Tank_Config *first;
Tank_Config *last;
```

having to include the asterisk before each variable name, rather than being able to use:

```
Tank_Config_Ptr first, last;
```

without having to specify the asterisk.  A related advantage is that it avoids the syntactic inconsistency with initializers.  If foo() is a function that returns a Tank_Config, a declaration of a pointer including an initializer would look like:

```
Tank_Config *myPointer = foo(); // Note the asterisk is needed here...
```

but subsequent assignments would look like:

```
myPointer = foo();  // ...but not here!
```

If one makes use of type typedef form, the code would look like:

```
Tank_Config_Ptr myPointer = foo(); // No asterisk here or in assignment
```

which uses the same syntax as the subsequent assignment.

Comment: *most significant advantage*: I'm afraid to differ, hiding pointers behind typedefs is actually very error prone, and leads to confusing code.

Comment: @chqrlie: Whether it's good or bad to hide pointers behind typedefs depends upon whether they're used more as a pointer to a thing, or as an abstract thing that happens to be a pointer.  For example, I think it would think that the `FILE` type in `<stdio.h>` would have been better as a pointer, since user code shouldn't need to care about whether it's a pointer to a struct, a pointer to a union, a pointer to a pointer, a pointer to an array, an index into a table, or anything else.  Saying `FILE f1,f2;` would seem more natural than having to say `FILE *f1,*f2;`.

Comment: That's correct, but in the OP's case, the pointer typedef is causing confusion, and it seems to be quite systematic for newbies to have this kind of problem. Teacher that routinely induce this kind of construction are not helping their students.

Answer (score 0):

The next two strings do the same:

1. ```
   Tank_Config * tank_config_ptr;
   ```
2. ```
   Tank_Config_Ptr tank_config_ptr;
   ```